# Resource to CreateWindowEx

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, resources

I'm doing some tests in msvc and C++. I'm trying to create dialog with ResEdit (available here http://www.resedit.net/) and when .RC file is created, I'm trying to use same values for CreateWindowEx API to create dialogues by native way (because resources can be edited and I don't want such thing). But, when I convert .RC values to CreateWindowEx, it becomes too small.. Can anyone suggest me what to do or a simple working code please?
Thank you.

Comment: *because resources can be edited and I don't want such thing* Binaries can be patched. What's your point?

Comment: Patched, but compared to editing, it's way too harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dialog units are not the same as pixel sizes.  From memory, a dialog unit by default represents 1.5 pixels.  So for a quick hack, scale your position and size values by 1.5.

But you should really use the `GetDialogBaseUnits` function, because the units are designed to scale with the system font.

Reference here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645475(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, was very useful for me. ;-)
P.S will accept after ~10 mins, can't accept now cause of filter.

Comment: Dialog units are 1/4 the width of the average character for the dialog's font at creation time and 1/8 the height of the font.  This is typically the ugly old system font that nobody uses anymore, but if you set up your dialog resource correctly, it can be relative to whatever font you're using for the dialog (but in those cases, GetDialogBaseUnits doesn't give you the right values).